# Como adicionar métodos personalizado em todos os serviços do spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Eu Implementei métodos em um `Repository` para todos os meus repositórios filhos tenha os mesmo métodos. Abaixa vai o código de como eu implementei um `Repository` Personalizado

**Esta é a interface:**

```
 @NoRepositoryBean
 public interface BaseMyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{

     List<T> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery);
 }
```

**Este é a implementação da classe:**

```
 public class BaseMyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseMyRepository<T, ID>{

     private final EntityManager entityManager;

     public BaseMyRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager){
         super(entityInformation, entityManager);
         this.entityManager = entityManager;
     }

     @Transactional
     @Override
     public List<T> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery) {
         List<T> lista = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, this.getDomainClass()).getResultList();

         return lista;
     }


 }
```

**Este é o meu repositório (`Repository`):**

```
 public interface MyRepository extends BaseMyRepository<SmaempreEntity, Integer>{

 }
```

Agora eu preciso saber se é possível fazer o código abaixo. Abaixo eu exemplifiquei do que eu preciso.

```java
 @Service
 @Transactional
 public class MyBaseService<R extends BaseMyRepository, E> {

     @Autowired
     private R;

     public List<E> findAll() {
         return R.findAll();
     }

    public List<E> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery) {
         return R.findCustomNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
     }
 }


 public class MyService extends MyBaseService<MyRepository, MyEntity> {


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui executar a classe de acordo com o que eu precisei acima. Abaixo vai o código e usei pra executar.

```java
 public class BaseMyService<R extends BaseMyRepository, E> {

     public String COLUMNS_RESUME = null;

     @Autowired
     private final R baseMyRepository;

     public BaseMyService(R myRepository) {
         this.baseMyRepository = myRepository;
     }


     public List<E> findAll() {
         return baseMyRepository.findAll();
     }

     public List<E> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery) {

         return baseMyRepository.findCustomNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
     }
 }


 @Service
 @Transactional
 public class MyService extends BaseMyService<MyRepository, MyEntity>{


     public MyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
         super(myRepository);
     }
 }
```

Dessa forma eu consegui customizar uma classe de serviços onde eu posso estender ela e usar os mesmos métodos em todos os serviços.

Answer (score 0):

Só de olhar assim é meio complicado, mas acredito que funcionaria.

Você tentou rodar o projeto e deu algum erro? Se sim, posta aqui o erro que podemos te ajudar melhor.